# Can you run python wikipedia api multiple times at the same time?

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have a list of all wikipedia articles and I want to scrape a body for research purposes. My script is working fine, but at the current speed this will take 40 days straight.

My questions is:

Can I run this script, lets say 10 times parallel in different terminal windows. If I just set it like this:

Script 1:
start point: 0
end point: len(list)/10

Script 2:
start start point: len(list)/10
end point: len(list)/(10*2)

...

Script 10

and so on.

This could leave me with 4 days, which is reasonable imo.

Does my approach work? Is there a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I will eventually :)(

Comment: So if anyone is wondering.. this actually works with no problems.

Comment: What Voxum says, but also, if you are extracting data from that many articles it would probably be faster to work from a database dump rather than fetching each article when you need it.

Comment: That’s what I’m trying to create - a database dump 

Comment: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/

Answer (score 0):

Possible yes, ideal no. Why do you think its running so slowly? Also are you using the wiki api or are you scraping the site? There's factors that affect either of the two so knowing what your actually doing will help us give a better answer.